# What is the shortcut for moving outside the scope one level when the cursor is on a brace?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

```
exampleObject = new Panel{
   if (this.exampleField ===1) {
   }
}
```

Cursor is on one of the inner braces. What is a shortcut for going to one of the outside braces?

I only posted the simple example for clarity of the question. My code is much more messy with dozens of blocks within a big block. A simple search will not suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know a single key combo, but
`<shift>-<right>, <ctrl-F>, <enter>`
will take you to the end of the outer block if you are on the trailing brace, and
`<shift>-<right>, <ctrl-F>, <shift>-F3`
will take you to the beginning if you are on the leading one.